# if an fcs fails does ethernet request a new frame?

Tags: networking, ethernet, tcp

So when you send a frame an fcs (32-bit crc) is applied at the tag end but if that fcs comes back as either corrupt or invalid will that device request a re-transmission or will it simply drop the frame?

Answer (score 0):

data frame at the destination will drop or discard invalid or corrupted frame details:

The source calculates this `FCS` prior to sending a frame, which is verified and compared at the destination. If the `FCS` data matches, the transmission is considered successful. If not, the data frame is automatically discarded due to error.
[explains Frame Check Sequence](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/24793/frame-check-sequence)

Answer (score 0):

There's no automatic retransmission at the Ethernet level; however, a higher-level protocol, such as TCP, may detect that a packet was lost and retransmit it.